# eslint error : Parsing error: The keyword 'export' is reserved

Tags: eslint, vue-cli

init a  project `test` with vue-cli

`test` vue project folder and `common` folder are at the same level.

```
D:/test
D:/common
```

import js from common files in `test`

```
import a  from '../../common/index'
```

eslint error

```
Failed to compile.
 ../common/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
D:\common\index.js
 2:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'export' is reserved
```

add `common` to eslint `ignorePatterns` not working

```
    ignorePatterns: ['**/common/**/*.js', 'common', '~/common/**', '**/common/**'],
```

add `/* eslint-disable */` into `common/index.js` also not working

how to solve ?